# fmi2: What is the unit of input parameter tolerance in the API "fmi2SetupExperiment"

Tags: fmi

I am implementing the slave for `fmi 2.0.` For the API

```
 fmi2SetupExperiment(fmi2Component c, 
 fmi2Boolean toleranceDefined, 
 fmi2Real tolerance, 
 fmi2Real startTime, 
 fmi2Boolean stopTimeDefined, 
 fmi2Real stopTime)
```

I understand that the tolerance parameter is used for the error estimation during the simulation.

I would like to know the unit/ value form of the `tolerance` parameter, for example if the `tolerance` is 5%, what would be the value of `tolerance`? 
Will it be 5 or 1.05 or some other form?

Answer (score 0):

The FMI 2.0 standard talks of "relative tolerance" on page 22.
This is not rigorously defined there, but correspond to relative tolerance values that are passed to a numerical solver. 
Many FMI importing tools, e.g., use the Sundials solvers.
The relative tolerances are explained there: https://computation.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/faq#cvode_tols .
So in your example I would expect 0.05 to be the right value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have understood it.

Answer (score 0):

The [FMI Specification 2.0](https://svn.modelica.org/fmi/branches/public/specifications/v2.0/FMI_for_ModelExchange_and_CoSimulation_v2.0.pdf) states that **usually** a relative tolerance is used which does not have a unit (% is not a unit, it merely stands for × 10^-2). 
So most likely, to pass a value of 5% as tolerance, you will have to pass 0.05 as `tolerance`.

The following is quoted from the [FMI Specification 2.0](https://svn.modelica.org/fmi/branches/public/specifications/v2.0/FMI_for_ModelExchange_and_CoSimulation_v2.0.pdf):

> Arguments *toleranceDefined* and *tolerance* depend on the FMU type:
>
> ## fmuType = fmi2ModelExchange:
>
> If `toleranceDefined = fmi2True` then the model is called with a numerical
>   integration scheme where the step size is controlled by using `tolerance` for error estimation **(usually as relative tolerance)**. 
>   In such a case, all numerical algorithms used inside the model (for example to solve non-linear algebraic equations) should also operate with an error estimation of an appropriate smaller relative tolerance.
>
> ## fmuType = fmi2CoSimulation:
>
> If `toleranceDefined = fmi2True` then the communication interval of the slave is controlled by error estimation. 
>   In case the slave utilizes a numerical integrator with variable step size and error estimation, it is suggested to use `tolerance` for the error estimation of the internal integrator **(usually as relative tolerance)**. 
>   An FMU for Co-Simulation might ignore this argument.

If you want to know exactly how this parameter is implemented, you have to ask the creator of your FMU - or look inside yourself if you can.

If you cannot look inside your FMU and the creator cannot tell you what it does internally, just change the value and compare the results and the run time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have understood it.